# Why `args` in method `warning` of class `Logger` is necessary in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I can use the code below to record the log:

```py
# method 1
>>> import logging
>>> user = "Jim"
>>> logging.warning("This is a warning from %s", user)
WARNING:root:This is a warning from Jim
```

However, I can also use the code blow to do the same thing:

```py
# method 2
>>> import logging
>>> user = "Jim"
>>> logging.warning("This is a warning from %s" %user)
WARNING:root:This is a warning from Jim
```

It seems that I can always use method 2 to record the log and the `args` in method `warning` of class `Logger` is unnecessary?

Can someone tell me what is the difference between method 1 and method 2?

Comment: The first method provides [additional data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) for the logger alongside the ordinary `printf`-style formatting

Answer (score 3):

The logging framework lets you turn levels on and off based on the level, where the message to going, etc.

The first method accepts a string and a tuple of objects. If your log entry is not going to be logged based on whatever criteria you have enabled, the string in not interpolated at all.

The second method interpolates the string immediately and passes the result to the logging framework. This may be expensive, since calling `str` and `repr` on arbitrary objects can execute any code. This is not efficient if, for example, your logging level is turned off.

The content of the string will be the same either way. The main difference is in when the arguments are interpolated, not how. Deferred interpolation (passing the args to the logger instead of doing it yourself) is much more efficient, when some logging levels or destinations are disabled.

Comment: and also using the arguments means that the LogRecord will contain those arguments (in the args field), and you can buld filters and handlers based on the data on the LogRecord.

Answer (score 2):

By using the separate args parameter means those arguments are included in the [LogRecord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logrecord-objects) that is passed to the filters, and you (or someone else) could write a filter which uses one or more of the args, or kwargs.

Edit : The answer above by [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist) is also correct that using args defers interpolation until the string is actually needed.

Comment: thanks for your help! Could you give an example of using a filter?

Comment: @kuzijiu I don't have any examples of writing filters - In my mind I ever wanted to write a filter, it would be because I was using a library that was logging everything, and I wanted to control what actually gets logged.
If you are building a library and using logging you should give your logger a sensible name (like the package name), so that users can identify and add handlers and filters to your log messages.

Answer (score 0):

In method1, warning will format the string for you. In method2, you will format the string yourself

Comment: But what's the practical difference?

Comment: As above - if you use the actual arguments (rather than self formatting), those arguments get included in the LogRecord, and are therefore available to the handlers and filters.